# Knockout using Mapping and Validation Plugins together. Getting client errors

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I'm using knockout js to construct my application with asp.net mvc 4 on the backend.  We are using knockout.mapping to populate the observables from MVC Service calls

Now I'm trying to add validation using the Knockout.Validation plugin as follows:

```
self.sDetail(ko.mapping.fromJS(s));
var validationOptions = { 
                          insertMessages: true, 
                          decorateElement: true,      
                          errorElementClass: 'errorFill' 
                         };
ko.validation.init(validationOptions);
self.sDetail.Year.extend({ required: true });
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to get property 'extend' of undefined or null reference
```

When I debug I find that the sDetail appears empty.  When I applyBindings the inputs are populated correctly.  At what point to I have access to the propertys of the ko viewmodel.  Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Are you inspecting the observable `sDetail` in your actual code or the value stored in it?

Comment: Jeff when set up I don't actually have to inspect anything, the validation just happens through the Knockout.Validation add in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution here: 
[Knockout Mapping Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933401/knockout-mapping-validation)

basically have to extend  the properties in the call to mapping

```
var validationMapping = {
// customize the creation of the name property so that it provides validation
Year: {
    create: function(options) {
        return ko.observable(options.data).extend( {required: true} );
    }
}
};


  self.sDetail(ko.mapping.fromJS(s,validationMapping));
 var validationOptions = { 
                      insertMessages: true, 
                      decorateElement: true,      
                      errorElementClass: 'errorFill' 
                     };
  ko.validation.init(validationOptions);
```

self.sDetail.Year.extend({ required: true });

Comment: At this point, it's probably better to create an explicit model, eh?

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem in your original code was that you were trying to access the `Year` property on the observable holding your mapped model, not on the model itself (assuming `sDetail` is an observable on `self` which I can only assume is your actual view model).  This was what I meant on my comment.  You mapped the *value* the observable holds so you need to read off of that value.  You attempted to `extend()` a property that doesn't exist on observables hence the error.

```
self.sDetail; // <- your observable holding the model
self.sDetail.Year; // <- undefined, observables don't have a `Year` property
self.sDetail.Year.extend(...); // <- error
```

The fix there would be to invoke your observable to get the model that it holds and then you can access whatever you want.

```
self.sDetail().Year.extend({ required: true }); // this should work
```

---

That's not to take away from your eventual solution, extending from within the mapping settings would be preferrable as it leads to cleaner code (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

For a cleaner and more readable solution use explicit declared VM's

```
DetailsViewModel = function(data) {
   this.year = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};
```

Used like

```
new DetailsViewModel(data);
```

A good practice is to explicit declare all members that do actual domain logic. The presentation only members can be automapped automatic by ko.mapping.

**Update:** Got downvoted by some douch, but this solution is very valid and readable

http://jsfiddle.net/hww8vk1n/1/

Comment: What happens to `this.year` when you call `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);`? Since it is already defined does the mapping plugin just assign a value to it at that point?

Comment: Yes, it will just execute the observable and assign value, it will keep the extensions etc. Got a downvote and noticed your comment, thats why the late reply :D

Comment: I like this example, what if I call `new DetailsViewModel();`

Comment: You could do ko.mapping.fromJS(data || { defaultProp: "defaultvalue" }, {}, this); http://jsfiddle.net/hww8vk1n/6/